# Dynamic title inside shell script using string

Tags: string, shell, dynamic

Can anyone help me?? how can i create title inside shell script so it set different title everytime i run different report.. for example if there are 3 reports.. Report1 Report2 n Report3.. how is it possible to change title automatically in shell script so when Report1 is run its going to say Report1 and when Report2 is run title automatically changes to Report2 and so on...

Comment: What is **title** for you? An environment variable? The title of the window (Konsole, for instance)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display "Report" followed by the value of a counting variable, it's really straightforward with, for instance, Bourne shell (Bash and others):

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in 1 2 3
do
    echo "Report $i"
done
```

Comment: Thanx for you reply but my title is in seperate script and my report is generated in different script.. i have to copy output  from both  different script and generate report in 3rd file

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you tell the script to run report1 vs report2 vs report3 you can just use that same method to change the title.

if you do "test.sh report1" to run 1 and "test.sh 2" to run report 2 you could do:

```
if [[ $! -ne 1]] then
  TITLE="report1"
else
   TITLE="report2"
fi
```

This is of course leaving out report3 but just use an elif for a third case.

sorry missed a closing bracket.

Comment: but my problem is i have main script that runs all 3 report and my title is in other script so when i run that main script i have to get specific title from other script and generate 3 report file which can be send as an attachment in a mail

Comment: so send the title as the second argument. If using bash this would be "script.sh arg1 arg2"  $0 is script name, $1 $arg1, $2 arg 2, $# would be the number of passed arguments.   Check this link out for more. [link] (http://www.linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial#4-passing-arguments-to-the-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

As karlphillip has said you haven't specified what you mean by title.

grantk's answer sets a variable called TITLE.

ChrisJ's shows the report name on the console output.

I'm going to assume you are running your scripts on a remote system using PuTTY and want to change the PuTTY window title.
[This](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/Xterm-Title) is a good guide to adjusting the window title and icon and this works with PuTTY.

In your case somewhere at the start of each report you can set the title using:

```
echo "\033]2;Executing Report 1\007"
```

and that should change the window title assuming you are sending your output to the console.

Give it a go and let me know.